# I am trying to Webscrape behind a password protected site from ESPN using R

Tags: html, r, url, rvest

I am trying to webscrape some data from ESPN using R and I am having trouble getting passed the login. I don't know if it is just because ESPN prevents webscraping or if I am missing something. Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://fantasy.espn.com/football/league/draftrecap?seasonId=2015&leagueId=1734728"
pgsession<-html_session(url)
read_html(url) #to make sure I am in the ESPN login page not the league page
```

After this step I think I go wrong. I don't know how to find the correct form needed for login

```
fantform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
fantform #to check the form I have
```

The response I get from checking this form is below. It doesn't seem right but if I change the form number I get an "error : subscript is out of bounds"

```
<form> '<unnamed>' (GET )
  <field> (search) :
```

The rest of the code I have is below but I am pretty sure I am stuck at this part.

```
filled_form <- html_form_set(pgform, "usernanerow" = "username", "passwordrow" = "password")
submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
Fantasy_league <- jump_to(pgsession, "https://fantasy.espn.com/football/league/draftrecap?seasonId=2015&leagueId=1734728")
```

I am very grateful for all responses/help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

They seem to make it really hard to find the login page and therefore difficult to find the login form, like you stated the form you get above isn't right.
If you can find the login page then just replace your first url with whatever the url is for the login page.

Apart from that the rest of the code is correct

If you're happy to use existing packages it seems like there's already one that might help with what you need:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fflr/vignettes/fantasy-football.html